# Concatenating layers in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to implement the code from this [paper](https://github.com/farhat-lab/wdnn) and as a beginner in deep learning, can not understand fully what they have done in generating a 'Wide and Deep Neural Network (WDNN) by concatenating layers. Here is the function they used to generate WDNN:

```
 def WDNN(data):
    input = Input(shape=(data.shape[1],))
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8))(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    wide_deep = concatenate([input, x])
    preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8))(wide_deep)
    model = Model(input=input, output=preds)
    opt = Adam(lr=np.exp(-1.0 * 9))
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Following the guidelines in the book 'Deep learning with Keras' written by Keras developer, I came up with the following function. But I cannot figure out how the original function is actually using concatenate and how I can implement it in my own code to perform the same? Any hints is appreciated.

```
def WDNN(data):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(256,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8), input_shape=(data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1,  activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
    # Compile model
    opt = Adam(lr=np.exp(-1.0 * 9))
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    return (model)
```

Comment: Sequential model can't achieve your goal. You need function model if you want to achieve `WDNN`. Please refer [Keras Models: Sequential vs. Functional](https://jovianlin.io/keras-models-sequential-vs-functional/).